# ajax call cant pass parameter to nodejs app

Tags: node.js, ajax

I make a ajax call via code below and expect to see parameters passed nodejs app, but it always empty

```
@action postData() {
    $.ajax({
  url:"http://localhost:8080/sendMail",
  ContentType:'application/json',
  dataType:'json',
  type:'post',
  data:JSON.stringify({'message':'helloworld'}),
  success:(result) =>{
  ..
})
```

If I make a post request within postman(adding raw string json parameters to body; {'message':'helloworld'})  its passed well and I see its logged. So whats wrong with this ajax call that i used in reactjsapp ?

Edited: it looks all parameters passed in browser fine but somehow nodejs unable to get them..
[image]

Comment: Try setting Content-Type, with `contentType: 'application/json'`, instead of `ContentType`. I also believe you do not need to stringify a JS Object as jQuery does it for you. Also it is not `type`, but `method: 'POST'`. Try those to begin with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `POST` data is sent in the HTTP body, you need to parse the JSON in there to get it. Assumed you use express.js on the server side, you could use [body-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser) to do that:

```
var express = require('express')
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')

var app = express()

// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded 
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

// parse application/json 
app.use(bodyParser.json())
```

Comment: Mr Joachim Schirrmacherm, I have been searching about issue for 15 hours, the line I copied of you; "app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))" is solved it, THANkS!